# Failed to start host 'dotnet$IdentityHost'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I open VS 2022, I encountering below error message. How can I fix the error.

I reinstalled/repaired the program.

> Could not start visual studio due to an error. StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Failed to start host 'dotnet$IdentityHost'. (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500)

Version: VS 2022 - 17.4.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is this ticket about it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-start-visual-studio-failed-to-start-host/1170525 dit you have a look at it?

The poster said that he solved it by disabling avast anti-virus.

Comment: I checked it but not worked because not related antivirus program for my issue.